# Failed to Compile After Installing Vuetify with Vue CLI 3

Tags: npm, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I tried to create a new Vue app with [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) by using the command from [Vuetify homepage](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start).

Following is the command I used:

```
npm install @vue/cli -g
vue create my-app // all options are default settings when creating
cd my-app
vue add vuetify // all options are default settings when running
```

All commands above mentioned completed perfectly. However, after I launch the hot-reload developing environment by the following command.

```
npm run serve
```

An error would occur as the following standard output.

```
> my-app@0.1.0 serve /home/seanwu/my-app
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
94% after seal                                                                        

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                    3:05:24 PM

error  in ./src/main.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /home/seanwu/my-app/src/main.js: /home/seanwu/my-app contains both .browserslistrc and package.json with browsers (While processing: "/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js$0")
    at /home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:239:15
    at eachParent (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:46:18)
    at Object.findConfig (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:219:20)
    at Function.loadConfig (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:150:37)
    at browserslist (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:187:31)
    at getTargets (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/targets-parser.js:133:50)
    at _default (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:184:46)
    at /home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at loadDescriptor (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:163:14)
    at cachedFunction (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:42:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:233:63)
    at config.presets.map.descriptor (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:68:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:66:38)
    at recurseDescriptors (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:92:27)
    at loadFullConfig (/home/seanwu/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:106:6)

@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.76:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I have no idea why this would happen as being new to front-end development and following every instruction from the [**Quick Start**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) web page. Maybe there are some stupid mistakes I made to cause this error.

Comment: It's so weird.. A few weeks ago, everything was fine. I ran the same commands and all was fine. Now, it's gone haywire

Comment: Have you found the solution? I tried `vue create <my-project>`, set up my project first (via Vue CLI 3), then do `vue add vuetify` and all I get is a bunch of `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.` on console.. Sad thing is, that it happens to one of the most popular framework of Vue..

Comment: In my case, it seems the **babel/polyfill** option in Vuetify installation requires **CSS Pre-processor** when I create Vue project. I've replied this around in the comment of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456930/8789738).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Node/npm version are you using? I'd assume the official tutorial works/worked at some point. I'd use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install different Node.js versions. That also changes the npm version. Then try `npm install` and `npm start` again.

Or you could delete `.browserslistrc` in `/home/seanwu/my-app`, so you don't have two conflicting files.

Comment: I am using Node.js `v8.10.0` and npm `3.5.2`. I do not have `.browserslistrc` file in `/home/seanwu/my-app` after the installations, so I am not sure about the confliction you mentioned. Interestingly, I find out if I select **CSS Pre-processors** feature when I create Vue app with custom settings or disable **babel/polyfill** when I add Vuetify plugin, I could fix this problem. Nevertheless, thank you so much for the answer and suggestion.